# Performance/efficiency of 2 SELECT statements vs UNION vs anything else in MySQL-PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, union, create-table

Which is more efficient/better practice/less costly in MySQL (with PHP)? `SELECT`ing two separate statements, `UNION`ing them into one, or something else I found online about `CREATE`ing a temporary table as the MySQL equivalent of `SELECT INTO`? Or anything else you can think of?

The result will be used in a PHP script.

Queries:

- The first `SELECT` (let's call it Query A) will always yield 10 rows, 4 columns no matter what.
- The second `SELECT` (Query B) will always yield 1 row, 4 columns no matter what.

Scenarios:

- If I `SELECT` the two statements, I will iterate Query B only if `Query A[0]->Col1 > 0` : total of 2 db queries + PHP processing.
- If I `UNION` the two statements into Query C in such a way that Query B will be the first row (`Query C[0]` is Query B) and Query A will be rows 2-11 (`Query C[1..10]` is Query A), I will only iterate rows 2-11 if `Query C[0]->Col1 > 0` : total of 1 db query + PHP processing.

Non-negotiables:

- I have to iterate over Query A no matter what.
- Query A's iteration depends on the value of Query B.

Is the 1 less `SELECT` query worth the `UNION` operation? Is there a more efficient/better practice/less costly solution to this? Anything I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm doubting there's much value in optimizing two queries that only return a total of 11 rows...

Comment: hmm.. so there's not much difference between firing a single `mysql_result` with the `UNION`ed query and firing 2 `mysql_result`s when the total result rows are just 11? in the end which do you suggest i go for, then? thanks much, @mellamokb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It totally depends on the environment and the way you are managing- I have to say- everything else. If the server is located on another network, on the other side of the planet, network is your bottleneck. 

To make a better call I would make some assumptions: the server is on localhost, the connections are managed properly, and it is just the query itself that should be optimized. If that's the case for you, you could use `Explain` command the usage as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) is very simple:

```
Explain select col1 from table1 Union select col2 from table2
```

There are tons of article out there explaining for you how to use `Explain`. [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377652&seqNum=2) is one.

One last thing, it is not just the number of rows that matter. It is also important how many times your select code is being executed too. Assume you have a loop which returns 11 rows on each run and has 1000 iterations. Just assume that the rows are different in each iteration, then you will see the effect of your connection management and caching.

Comment: now that's more like it. yes, this is for a standard deployment, nothing fancy. thank you thank you for that. for this particular web app, it'll just be called once per page. however, the number of times the page will be called must definitely scale well. i shall lookup explain and check out the goody goodness it has to offer. many thanks! will update this question once i finally decide on what  to do. you rock, @Jermin

Comment: k, so i ended up using the UNION. definitely worth it for scaling page requests.