# Using Union or run query twice

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have to run a query which retrieves records from two databases. The query is the same for both databases and I use the UNION relationship to just made one query.

The following example will describe what I actually want to do

```
SELECT col1 FROM db1.table1 UNION SELECT col1 FROM db2.table1 ;
```

I am using php to execute the above query so I need to know which is better for performance run the above query once or make two queries and merge the results by php

```
SELECT col1 FROM db1.table1
SELECT col1 FROM db2.table1
```

please note that I am using a complicated mysql queries which uses regex and sometimes i use subqueries.

Thanks

Comment: For selecting the records from a different DB, you need to use different connection string. You should have 2 connection string - one is for 1st DB and another one for 2nd DB. So, I guess, UNION will not work over here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255746/performance-efficiency-of-2-select-statements-vs-union-vs-anything-else-in-mysql

Comment: Benchmark it. It's the only way to know. The union is _probably_ slightly quicker.

Comment: @KA_lin I don't have a problem with connection I have tried it and it's working. My question is about performance which is better Make a double query for each database or make a single query for each one aline and merge the results by php

Comment: @MohammedIbrahim: The question in the link starts out like this:'Which is more efficient/better practice/less costly in MySQL (with PHP)? SELECTing two separate statements, UNIONing them into one, or something else...' it`s the same thing, have you read the whole thread?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to be sure is to benchmark it, which I haven't. The following is my best guess about the differences, assuming that:

- In both cases there is some post processing in PHP (e.g. printing a result to a browser),
- You will always run both queries together (either both are in query cache or none).
- If you run them separately you implement the duplicate row removal in PHP.

**If there are no duplicate rows:**

The union should be faster by a constant amount of time (e.g. 30ms), because of the overhead of running 2 queries instead of one.

**If there are duplicate rows:**

The union will save you some traffic and PHP processing and might get noticeably faster (if there are a lot of duplicates).